# How to group test cases of each feature in a test plan

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, gui-testing

In our project I found the test cases were duplicated appearing in each feature group. To demonstrate this problem, I created a small project.

[image]

**Demo project**
`https://github.com/Haibo-Zhou/TestPlanTackle`

**Test file structure:**

`AutomatedRegression -> MyXCTestBase -> XCTestCase`

And all test cases are under AutomatedRegression, Feature groups A & B include the test cases, and they both have a class file for grouping use.

[image]

The problem is after creating a test plan for it, each feature group will include all the tests, which you could see from above screenshot. And I think the reason is that they all inherit from AutomatedRegression class.

So how could I group them properly? Because we should be able run a specific feature group in a test plan.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "properly." Can you give an example of what you want? For example, do you want something Feature B specific?

Comment: Hey, I want FeatureA group only hold its own tests (e.g. test_FA_xxx), and vice versa for FeatureB group. Currently, each group include all tests in Test Plan.

Comment: I see the problem from looking at the example you posted on GitHub. But for this question to make sense to others, please show FA-001.swift, AutomatedRegression.swift, and MyXCTestBase.swift. And can you explain your goal in this arrangement: what do you want to reuse across your tests?